# Can iOS boot time drift?

Tags: ios, time, unix-timestamp

I'm using this code to determine when my iOS device last rebooted:

```
int mib[MIB_SIZE];
size_t size;
struct timeval boottime;

mib[0] = CTL_KERN;
mib[1] = KERN_BOOTTIME;
size = sizeof(boottime);
if (sysctl(mib, MIB_SIZE, &boottime, &size, NULL, 0) != -1) {
    return boottime.tv_sec;
}

return 0;
```

I'm seeing some anomalies with this time. In particular, I save the long and days and weeks later check the saved long agains the value returned by the above code.

I'm not sure, but I think I'm seeing some drift. This doesn't make any sense to me. I'm not converting to NSDate to prevent drift. I would think that boot time is record by the kernel when it boots and isn't computed again, it is just stored. But could iOS be saving boot time as an NSDate, with any inherent drift problems with that?

Comment: Can you give an example of the drift you are seeing?

Comment: At least 5 seconds difference when between the saved boot time and the "computed" boot time. I would expect zero drift. And... I might not even being drifting, I'm just doing some detective work based on bug reports from the field. I've never seen boot time vary at all. An authoritative answer here saying, "Yes, it can drift" makes it easier to fix.

Comment: My iPad Mini 3 drifted 48 seconds over the weekend!

Comment: Hmmm - that's unusual.  I've no idea why it would do that.

Comment: Clocks drift, I'm just very surprised that boot time is computed using the device clock. It should be a constant.

Comment: But even a sundial doesn't drift by 48 seconds in 48 hours?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the iOS Kernel is closed-source, it's reasonable to assume most of it is the same as the OSX Kernel, which is [open-source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/xnu).

Within `osfmk/kern/clock.c` there is the function:

```
/*
 *  clock_get_boottime_nanotime:
 *
 *  Return the boottime, used by sysctl.
 */
void
clock_get_boottime_nanotime(
    clock_sec_t         *secs,
    clock_nsec_t        *nanosecs)
{
    spl_t   s;

    s = splclock();
    clock_lock();

    *secs = (clock_sec_t)clock_boottime;
    *nanosecs = 0;

    clock_unlock();
    splx(s);
}
```

and `clock_boottime` is declared as:

```
static uint64_t     clock_boottime;             /* Seconds boottime epoch */
```

and finally the comment to this function shows that it can, indeed, change:

```
/*
 *  clock_set_calendar_microtime:
 *
 *  Sets the current calendar value by
 *  recalculating the epoch and offset
 *  from the system clock.
 *
 *  Also adjusts the boottime to keep the
 *  value consistent, writes the new
 *  calendar value to the platform clock,
 *  and sends calendar change notifications.
 */
void
clock_set_calendar_microtime(
    clock_sec_t         secs,
    clock_usec_t        microsecs)
{
    ...
```

**Update to answer query from OP**

I am not certain about how often `clock_set_calendar_microtime()` is called, as I am not familiar with the inner workings of the kernel; however it adjusts the `clock_boottime` value and the `clock_bootime` value is initialized in `clock_initialize_calendar()`, so I would say it can be called more than once.   I have been unable to find any call to it using:

```
$ find . -type f -exec grep -l clock_set_calendar_microtime {} \;
```

Comment: Is clock_set_calendar_microtime only called when the kernel boots? That's ok if it is called once. The value should change then, of course. But if it is called when asking for the boot time, then that is bad since the boot time will be dependent on the platform clock, which is bad for me.

Comment: That function does indeed call "clock_boottime += secs - clock_calend.epoch;" but it isn't clear to me who calls that function.

Comment: http://devetc.org/code/2014/01/21/timers-clocks-and-cocoa.html is an interesting read for clock geeks.

Comment: to my understanding, when the user goes into settings and changes the time manually, the boot time is changed by the delta to the new time to keep the interval between boot time and system time, equal. but it does not "drift" as it is a timestamp, only the system clock itself drifts.

Answer (score 1):

RE my comment above...

> "to my understanding, when the user goes into settings and changes the
>   time manually, the boot time is changed by the delta to the new time
>   to keep the interval between boot time and system time, equal. but it
>   does not "drift" as it is a timestamp, only the system clock itself
>   drifts."

I'm running NTP on my iOS app, and speak with Google's time servers.

I feed NTP the uptime since boot (which doesn't pause and is correctly adjusted if some nefarious user starts messing with system time... which is the whole point of this in the first place), and then add the offset between uptime since boot and epoch time to my uptime.

```
inline static struct timeval uptime(void) {

   struct timeval before_now, now, after_now;

   after_now = since_boot();

   do {
      before_now = after_now;
      gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
      after_now = since_boot();

   } while (after_now.tv_sec != before_now.tv_sec && after_now.tv_usec != before_now.tv_usec);


   struct timeval systemUptime;
   systemUptime.tv_sec = now.tv_sec - before_now.tv_sec;
   systemUptime.tv_usec = now.tv_usec - before_now.tv_usec;

   return systemUptime;
 }
```

I sync with the time servers once every 15 minutes, and calculate the offset drift (aka on system clock drift) every time.

```
static void calculateOffsetDrift(void) {

   static dispatch_queue_t offsetDriftQueue = dispatch_queue_create("", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
   static double lastOffset;

   dispatch_barrier_sync(offsetDriftQueue, ^{

      double newOffset = networkOffset();

      if (lastOffset != 0.0f) printf("offset difference = %f \n", lastOffset - newOffset);

      lastOffset = newOffset;
   });
 }
```

On my iPhone Xs Max the system clock usually runs around 30ms behind over 15 minutes.

Here's some figures from a test I just ran using LTE in NYC..

```
+47.381592 ms
+43.325684 ms
-67.654541 ms
+24.860107 ms
+5.940674  ms
+25.395264 ms
-34.969971 ms
```

Comment: So you are seeing a total of about 100ms drift. That's nowhere near the 48 seconds I was seeing. Remember, I was looking at the reboot time.

Comment: right but the boot time is just a timestamp. and it’s only changed when the system time is changed in so far as to keep the seconds SINCE boot equivalent. So the boot time may jump 50 seconds, but only when the system clock jumps 50 seconds, so that the differential between the two remains the same.

Comment: exactly! Yes, that's why I'm puzzled by what I observed. You've measured 100ms of drift, I observed 48 seconds. I don't think drift can explain that.