# CMAltitudeData has some weird data at the end, any ideas?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-motion

I've been playing with Core Motion's framework lately and while trying to get more juice to come out of the limited CMAltitude class just stumbled with some weird data at the end of the call. So to recreate if you call up:

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion


class ViewController: UIViewController {

let corey = CMAltimeter()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.getter()
}

@objc func getter() {
    corey.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main, withHandler: { (altitudeData:CMAltitudeData?, error:Error?) in
        print(String(describing: altitudeData.unsafelyUnwrapped))
```

Just for the visual purposes doing this really scratchy thing will respond with:

```
Altitude -0.589237 Pressure 101093.882812 @ 2377.566172
Altitude -0.618303 Pressure 101094.234375 @ 2378.602637
Altitude -0.618303 Pressure 101094.234375 @ 2379.640150
Altitude -0.620945 Pressure 101094.250000 @ 2380.678124
Altitude -0.628872 Pressure 101094.343750 @ 2381.714421
```

What I would like to know is the last part `@ 2381.714421`, it looks like seconds but actually I'm not really sure, when comparing with a timer, and with boottime `time_t` that number start +4 seconds, after some time of inactivity it drifts and becomes less time than boottime.

Does it drifts away because of app inactivity?
But how come that it starts with more time than even boot-time?

Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

`CMAltitudeData` inherits from `CMLogItem`, this is where the last field, `timestamp` is coming from. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmlogitem/1615939-timestamp), `timestamp` should match the amount of time in seconds since the device booted.

However, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237715/can-ios-boot-time-drift) question on SO the boot time can indeed drift slightly and it seems that `timestamp` doesn't simply copy `time_t` at each measurement, but rather it copies it at the first measurement and after that it just increments it based probably on a different `Timer`. Comparing to a `Timer` is not a good idea, since `Timer` runs on a runloop, so it only works while your app is in the foreground and even then it isn't really precise.